# Dependency injection with very different requirements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC app that will need to connect to a third party WCF service but will probably move to a REST API in the future. I can nicely split out the app into various UI elements, View Models, interfaces, and implementations such as IRegister, ILogon, etc. and then potentially have WCF and REST versions of each.

The problem is for DI, I'd want to pass in a connection as part of the constructor of each. The nature of the WCF connection is a large Interface/contract object that then links to all available methods of the third party system. The REST connection needs to pass in an already established authorization token, and then make a series of API calls.

How would I implement the actual connection, would I just use a data type of "object".

Comment: First of all, can you tell us which DI framework you're using?

Comment: simply implement a class for the WCF service point, and inject the class then?

Comment: Introduce unified abstraction(interface) and implement it for each service.

Comment: "better" how? Sounds like you're asking for opinions, which is specifically off-topic for Stack Overflow. You might be able to [edit] your question to remove the opinion request, however, but it may fall into the "too broad" category. Perhaps if you included more specifics about what you're using for DI and what the different connection interfaces look like?

Comment: "Injecting runtime data into your application components is a code smell. Runtime data should flow through the method calls of already-constructed object graphs.It causes ambiguity, complicates the Composition Root with an extra responsibility, and makes it extraordinarily hard to verify the correctness of your DI configuration."

Comment: In answer to the above questions, better as in something more testable and modular but not too complicated. Modest though my own skills are, the person who inherits it will probably be more junior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it that you are trying to inject some sort of connection settings into some kind of repository. Depending on the methods called in the repository you are either calling an "old" WCF API or a "new" REST API. Since the WCF client is probably generated by making a Service Reference. The client itself can be injected.

For the REST API you would need some sort of factory that will retrieve first the security token and then return a self implemented REST client which has the token passed through its constructor. Of course depending on the lifetime of the token you might have to take different approaches to make sure your token remains valid.

The REST client would expose the required methods to make the calls passing the security token along with each request. The HttpClient class allows for default headers to be sent with every subsequent request. Making it very easy.

Comment: Correct, it is somewhat based on a monolithic system that passes the client around. I'm trying to create interfaces, IRegister, ILookup etc with a connection property generic enough that it could accept either a WCF client, a REST factory class or possibly some other connection method in the. future.  What type of type, class or interface would the property need to be?

Answer (score 0):

Create seperate class for Service and implement the interface as well

Example class  : - SignInService.cs
        Interface : - ISignInService

Then inject your service class via interface in startup.cs
Example -

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {           
       services.AddTransient<ISignInService, SignInService>();
    }
```